# Select last variable of an Observable stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a variable 'messages' that contains messages from a conversation:

```
messages: Observable<Message[]>;
```

I fill my variable 'messages' like this:

```
const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
newThread.messages = Observable.of([newMessage]);
```

I would like my lastMessage variable to automatically contain the last message in the 'messages' variable:

```
lastMessage: Message = null;
```

Here's what I did, it does not work:

```
const messagesThread: Thread = threads[message.thread.id];
      if (!messagesThread.lastMessage ||
        messagesThread.lastMessage.date < message.date) {
        messagesThread.lastMessage = message;
      }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT

It's my function to add a new message :

```
addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
    const flo: User = new User(objMessage.author, objMessage.site);
    const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, [flo]);
    const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);

    objMessage.date = moment().toDate();

    newThread.messages = Observable.of([newMessage]);
    newThread.messages.last().subscribe((message) => {
      newThread.lastMessage = message;
    });                    //DOESN'T WORK

    objMessage.thread = newThread;

    this.addMessage(newMessage);
    this.addThread(newThread);
 }
```

I initialize my variables like that :

```
messages: Observable<Message[]>;
lastMessage: Message = null;
```

I have this error :

```
Type 'Message[]' is not assignable to type 'Message'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `.last();` operator

Example from source

var source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 10).last();

```
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

// => Next: 9
// => Completed
```

like this :

```
 newThread.messages.last().subscribe((message)=>{

         console.log('last messages',messages);
   newThread.lastMessage = messages /// NOT that this is messages as an array
 });
```

NOTE :

You have an `Observable` of messages, so every event will give you a `message` array, NOT a `message`

If you don't want that, you got to get rid of that array, I'm not sure what is it that you're trying to achieve here

Comment: Like this : `newThread.messages = Observable.of([newMessage]);
newThread.lastMessage = newThread.messages.last();`

I have this error : 

`Type 'Observable<Message[]>' is not assignable to type 'Message'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Observable<Message[]>'.`

Comment: Sorry finally it works with that : `newThread.messages.last().subscribe((message) => {
          [newThread.lastMessage] = message;
        });`

Thank you :)